# HTTPError: 500 while trying to post data using requests.post() in Django framework (python program)

Tags: python, django, dictionary, python-requests, internal-server-error

Somebody Kindly help me out here. I'm trying to process few text files in a directory and convert them into dictionary. Then I'm trying to upload through the DJANGO REST API using `requests.post()` but I'm getting 
`requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http://34.72.26.221/feedback`.

My code is as follows:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import requests
import glob

dirloc = r"/data/feedback/"
d = {}
for file in glob.iglob(dirloc+ '*'):
        if not file.startswith('.'):
            with open(file,'r') as f:
                d["title"] = f.readline().strip("\n")
                d["name"] = f.readline().strip("\n")
                d["date"] = f.readline().strip("\n")
                d["feedback"] = f.readline().strip("\n")
                print(d) #used for troubleshooting only#
                r = requests.put("http://34.72.26.221/feedback/", data = d)
                print(r.status_code)
```

I'm new to coding and still figuring out things. So this post may be missing some needed info. Please let me know if I need to add anything.

Comment: You're not using `post` you're using `put` with `requets.put`.

Comment: Damn. So silly of me. Thank you for pointing out that. I'll correct it and will try again.

Comment: Great. That solved my problem. Thanks a ton. Have a great day.

Comment: Nice, glad I could help! Please accept the answer below to mark the question as solved! Consider upvoting also ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `post` you're using `put` with `requets.put`.

Change your `requests` usage to:

```
r = requests.post("http://34.72.26.221/feedback", data = d)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error tells 5**, there is an issue with your django view. If possible please share your django view code to help you reslove the issue

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this silly question. Can you please tell me where I can find this view code?

Comment: If you have the django project code. Please refer this  (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/)

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a typo error. Let me correct that and try again. If I'm still unable to solve that, I'll get back to you. Thank you for the response.